# Getting rid of flickering in 2d object displayed on 3d space

Tags: processing

**The problem**

[image]

Im trying to develop one of those [amazing 3d map visualization](https://youtu.be/4gIhRkCcD4U?t=44s) using processing. Im getting that flickering effect on my ellipses one I move the map. How can I fix that?

**The code**

```
PImage europeMapImage;
MercatorMap mercatorMap;

PVector berlin;
PVector london;
PVector venice;
PVector istanbul;


void setup() {
  europeMapImage = loadImage("europe.jpg");
  size(900, 500, P3D);
  smooth();

  MercatorMap mercatorMap = new MercatorMap(900, 500, 68.75, 33.86, -34.71, 85.34);

  berlin = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(52.5, 13.34));
  london = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(51.5f, -0.1f));
  venice = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(45.44, 12.34));
  istanbul = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(41.01, 28.98));
}

void draw() {
  background(#000000);
  camera(mouseX, 2*mouseY, 400, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  image(europeMapImage, 0, 0, width, height);
  fill(0, 255, 200, 200);

  stroke(#ffffff, 200);
  line(berlin.x, berlin.y, venice.x, venice.y);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(berlin.x, berlin.y, 12, 12);
  ellipse(london.x, london.y, 12, 12);
  ellipse(venice.x, venice.y, 12, 12);
  ellipse(istanbul.x, istanbul .y, 12, 12);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) to me, try to simply move the ellipses higher on Z a bit.

Here's a rough test (not tested - z value might be positive or negative):

```
PImage europeMapImage;
MercatorMap mercatorMap;

PVector berlin;
PVector london;
PVector venice;
PVector istanbul;


void setup() {
  europeMapImage = loadImage("europe.jpg");
  size(900, 500, P3D);
  smooth();

  MercatorMap mercatorMap = new MercatorMap(900, 500, 68.75, 33.86, -34.71, 85.34);

  berlin = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(52.5, 13.34));
  london = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(51.5f, -0.1f));
  venice = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(45.44, 12.34));
  istanbul = mercatorMap.getScreenLocation(new PVector(41.01, 28.98));
}

void draw() {
  background(#000000);
  camera(mouseX, 2*mouseY, 400, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  image(europeMapImage, 0, 0, width, height);
  fill(0, 255, 200, 200);
  pushMatrix();//isolate coordinate system
  translate(0,0,10);//play with the z value to for better results
  stroke(#ffffff, 200);
  line(berlin.x, berlin.y, venice.x, venice.y);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(berlin.x, berlin.y, 12, 12);
  ellipse(london.x, london.y, 12, 12);
  ellipse(venice.x, venice.y, 12, 12);
  ellipse(istanbul.x, istanbul .y, 12, 12);
  popMatrix();//return to Processing's regular coordinate system

}
```